# Let angular to know a new html element had been created

Tags: angularjs

I created a new (the second div) html element dynamically by the following code:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var container = document.createElement('div');
var node = document.createTextNode('Hello, {{ name }}');
container.appendChild(node);
body.appendChild(container);
```

Add, my index.html like this:

```
<html ng-app>
<body>
<div>
 Hello, {{ name }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Well, the first `Hello, {{name}}` works well, it shows `Hello,World`. but the second one `Hello, {{name}}`, just shows `<div>Hello, {{name}}</div>`, How can I let the angular to know I have create a new element, and let it to explain the value?

Comment: Really, you shouldn't do that. That's not how the framework works. Use a ng-repeat in the view, that itarates over an array in the model. To create a new HTML element, just add an object to the array in the model, and the angular will add a corresponding HTML element in the view.

Comment: Use a directive and never use DOM manipulation, then you can $observe attrbutes and you've done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to use the $compile service.

From plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zijB2HM8OSblvmuu1jn9?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $document) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  var d;
  $scope.add = function() {
    var document = $document[0];
    var node = document.createTextNode('Hello Sweet {{name}}');
    var el = $compile(node)($scope);
    if(!d) {
      d = $document.find('div');
    }
    console.log('l=',d.length);
    d.append(el);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to lazy load of angular.
Instead of directly binding the modal you can call a function

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var container = document.createElement('div');
var node = document.createTextNode('Hello, {{ myFoo()}}');
container.appendChild(node);
body.appendChild(container);
```

and in your controller define myFoo like this

```
$scope.myFoo = function(){
    return "My Custom Text";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you the following answer which is more in the idea of angularjs. In the JS side, create an array which the names that you want to display and if you want to add a new functio updating your data.

In the HTML side, just use the `ng-repeat` directive to print your names.

```
<html ng-app='myapp'>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller='ctrl'>
        <ul ng-repeat="name in names">
            <li> Hello {{name}} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>

<script>
        var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);

        app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {


            $scope.names = ["foo","bar"];

        });
</script>
```

Also, I give the jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/xjtmp27u/